# What is the equivalent to R_HISTFILE for R data files

Tags: r, configuration

.RData files are starting to invade my directory structure. I would like to retain a single one in a specified directory.  Is there such an ENV variable similar to R_HISTFILE?

This is in reference to the default save/restore directory for R workspaces.

**UPDATE** The answer by JThorpe led to the following solution:

- set Env var RPROFILE_USER to a desired location . I am using my home dir

i.e.:

```
export RPROFILE_USER=/Users/steve
```

- In that directory create a file with setwd (set working directory)

i.e:

```
$cat  ~/.Rprofile
setwd('/Users/steve')
```

Now the .RData will always load/save to the home dir (or whatever dir you put in setwd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally dislike having R retain anything between sessions b/c it makes for difficult to find errors owing to variables that persist between sessions. Hence I set the “no-save” and “no-restore” options so that R neither writes its current state to an .Rdata file nor attempts to read in an old state.  If I do happen to want to save an R session (this happens VERY rarely) I call `savehistory()`.

Methods for setting command line options in OSX can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/271678/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-dock-items), and what follows describes setting command line options for R (or any other program) in windows.

To set the no-save and no-restore options in Windows, right-click on the R icon that you use to start an R session and select the ‘properties’ option.  In the properties box, the “target” string should look something like this:

```
“C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin\i386\Rgui.exe”
```

To this string, add this string ‘ --no-save --no-restore’.  Note that there is a space before each of the double-dashes.  The target should now look something like this:

```
 “C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin\i386\Rgui.exe” --no-save --no-restore
```

Click ‘Ok’ or ‘Apply’ to save these options.  Note that these are per-icon (shortcut) settings.  I have several icons with different command line options depending on the setting I want in the R session.    Additional command line arguments to R can be found [here.](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Invoking-R-from-the-command-line)

Comment: That is your opinion, but does answer the OP.  I do prefer having reload. If you have  another answer that actually answers the OP feel free tp add.

Comment: I suspect that R saves the .Rdata in the current working directory, and that you are starting R from the terminal and it's leaving an .Rdata file wherever you open R.  If you create a file called ".Rprofile" in this directory `path.expand('~')`  you can call `setwd('\my\favorite\dir')` to set it at start up or place the call to `setwd()` in a function called `.last` in that file to set on exit.  See [this page](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html) for details.  That solves the saving problem, and you'll need to do something similar to read the correct .Rdata file at startup.

Comment: Actually you may need to put the above suggestion in your `Rprofile.site` file, as detailed [here](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html), since R only looks for the .Rprofile in you current working directory...

Answer (score 1):

Try the `Load` command in the Hmisc package.  It uses the `LoadPath` option for this.

Comment: Updated OP to specify the question is in regard to where workspaces are saved/restored by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `.Rprofile` file you can specify a default working directory. See `?Startup` for more details including the ability to set a site-wide profile. I just referred to that help page to make sure the .RData would be affected by that setting.